# ngclass strike in angular

Tags: html, angular, checkbox, strikethrough

I'm making a project in angular. When i click on the checkbox i want that there is a line trough the text. But when i click on the checkbox nothing happens ..

Can you help me ?

Thanks !

```
  <h3>Todos list</h3>
<ul class="list-group">
   <li *ngFor="let todo of todos; let i = index" class="list-group-item">
     {{todo.text}}
 <p [ngClass]="{strike: deleted}">test</p>

<label>
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="deleted">
</label>

<button class="btn btn-danger btn-small" (click)="deleteTodo(i)">X</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is your li tag closed? And try to give ng-true-value to input checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, in Angular it's `[(ngModel)]`, not `ng-model` as in `AngularJs`.

Also, you can't have a single variable (`deleted`) to handle all *items* in your `*ngFor`.

To make it wok apply the changes:

```
...
<p [ngClass]="{strike: todo.deleted}">test</p> 

<label>
  <input type="checkbox" 
         [(ngModel)]="todo.deleted"> 
</label> 
...
```

[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/AYEZEIT7cPhhiI4Rc6IM?p=info)

Comment: *"It doesn't work"* is too vague. Why isn't it working? Any errors? Also, don't edit your code accordingly my answer. Please, rollback your changes and keep the original code in question!

Comment: no errors , but when i click on the checkbox nothing happens

Comment: I included a demo in my answer. Check it please.

Comment: i checked it but i don't write my code in the .ts file , i write my code in a .html file and then i load this template in my .ts  file. But i tried you're way and added the code to the component in the .ts file and it still doesn't work. When i click on checkbox notting happens

Comment: What? Man.. it's just a plunker (**DEMO**) that I made to demonstrate that the approach I suggested really works. Where you write your template doesn't make difference.. you can write it in template or in a single file, it's the same thing! By the way, what do you have in your CSS, specifically in `strike` *class*?

Comment: It works , i just forgot the code in my css file ! sorry for the truble. Thanks for the help

Comment: No problem, can you check it as answer?

Answer (score 0):

use `<s>` tag instead of `<strike>` tag
Ex:
if you want `<strike> Not Aailable </strike>`
and it is not supported by angular 4 and above versions then,
use `<s>Not Available</s>`